# Post ID of a particular public URL of Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to access the Post Id of public url "
http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/world/middle-east/Saudi-Arabias-Prince-Mohammed-bin-Salman-unveils-sweeping-plans-to-end-addiction/articleshow/51990106.cms" using the facebook graph api in java.

I am able to get all the posts from the page. But i want only the post whose url is mentioned above.

Comment: then search all the posts content for this url there is no way to search posts by content;

Comment: Thanks.I can find all the posts for the particular page. But how will i find the post for that particular URL? Currently i am using the facebook4j apis

Comment: You can’t. There is no search for public posts any more.